# Getting user id or other info from user_register in WP

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I'm trying to extract or get atleast the user_id upon registration in WP using user_register hook. But the alert doesn't even shows up.

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'display_id' );

function display_id( $user_id ) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Registration successful");</script>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'display_id', 10, 1);

function display_id( $user_id ) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Registration successful");</script>';
}
```

Comment: How can I test to show the user_id, let's say, show it in footer?

Comment: You can alert user_id by this:    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Registration of user <?php echo $user_id; ?> successful");</script>';

Comment: I tried this..

add_action('user_register', 'my_new_member');
function my_new_member($user_id) {
 if (isset($_POST['first_name'])) {
  $firstname = $_POST['first_name'];
 }
 else {
  $firstname = '';
 }
 
 
 echo $user_id, $firstname;
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'my_new_member' );

Comment: Registration page reloads and nothing happens. :(